# $F$ is subfield of complex field $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $F$ is field with characteristic $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

We know that subfield of field is set $F$ of complex number which itself is a field under usual multiplication and addition. but how to show that it has characteristic $0$?

Comment: How do you define characteristic zero? Because my definition makes it pretty obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Because subfield and extension feild always have the same characteristic?
After all the characteristic is obtained from the prime field, i.e., the smallest subfield (which is the same for subfield and extension field, as it it is loosely speaking just generated from $0$ and $1$), so here $\mathbb Q$.

Another definition: Consider the kernel of the additive group homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to F$ given by $1\mapsto 1$. This also doesn't change when extending / switching to a subfield.